# Multiplication of distributions and solutions to ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I still have some problems understanding the lack of a reasonable notion of distributional product. Let me give you a simple example: consider the ODE on the line
$$
\partial_x f(x) = -f^2(x),
$$ 
then $f(x)=1/x$ is solution for each $x\neq 0$. I would like to solve this equation in the sense of distributions in $\mathbb R$, but $1/x$ does not define a distribution, and if we replace it by its principal value, then I have problems multiplying twice.

So, what can I do? Is it really meaningless the above equation, when considered in the sense of distributions? Notice that $1/(x+i\varepsilon)$ is now a well-defined solution (even in the sense of distributions), for any $\varepsilon \neq 0$. Any comment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One little point, which perhaps you already know, is that the limit of the distributions $1/(x+i\varepsilon)$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$ is not simply the principal value of $1/x$, but adds to that a multiple of Dirac delta at $0$ (with sign depending on which side we approach from)... But, yes, even if we try to be subtle and refer to wavefront sets to multiply, this essentially never allows us to square a distribution.